# Bash: how to change first column of a file and only the first column

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, awk, text-parsing

I have a file that was screwed up by a program and now every line looks something like this:

```
somelongstring:number   number    number   number   ... a lot more columns
```

(Tab delimited)
What I need to do is modify every line such that the first column, if it is in the format somelengthystring:number, is changed to just number (get rid of the string and the colon)

I know that I can use split in awk to get rid of the string and colon like:

```
awk '{
   split($1,array,":")
} 
END{
   print array[2],$2,$3...
}'
```

But the thing is that I don't want just the first column. I want the entire line and just want the first column to be fixed. The only problem is that there are so many columns that it'd be rather stupid to type out $2,$3, ... all the way to $35 or whatever it is. What is a better way to fix this?

Comment: Does *somelongstring* have space in it?

Comment: Possibly. As far as I can tell, no, and it shouldn't. But the file is about 500MB in size so couldn't check every line.

Comment: If it has space or colons, it can get hairy. I'm trying to think of how to deal with those cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed`. Remove all characters from the beginning of the line (`^`) until first colon.

```
sed 's/^[^:]*://' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl you can do this:

```
cat file.txt | perl -pe 's/.*?://'
```

Answer (score 1):

If what you have works so far, except for the $2, .... part:

```
awk '{
    split(..)
    $1=array[2]
    print
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut)

```
cut -d: -f2- file.txt
```

This uses the colon as a delimiter and keeps everything to the right of it.

Answer (score 0):

If only the format `somelengthystring:number` in the first TAB-delimited field should be changed, you could try this:

```
awk '$1~/:[0-9]*$/{sub(/.*:/,x,$1)}1' FS='\t' OFS='\t' file
```